# PHP Date Formatting

Tags: php, date

When I write this  `strftime("%b %d, %Y %l:%I %p" ,strtotime($runrows['date']));` it always displays incorrectly (as in it displays 10:10 or 1:01 or 4:04)

Im trying to diplay the date as July 4, 20ll 7:32 pm

How would I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you give us an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: i edited it to show how I wanted it to look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you post what you get from `$runrows['date']`?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Here are few examples:

```
// Outputs: 12/28/2002 - %V,%G,%Y = 52,2002,2002
echo "12/28/2002 - %V,%G,%Y = " . strftime("%V,%G,%Y", strtotime("12/28/2002")) . "\n";

// Outputs: 12/30/2002 - %V,%G,%Y = 1,2003,2002
echo "12/30/2002 - %V,%G,%Y = " . strftime("%V,%G,%Y", strtotime("12/30/2002")) . "\n";

// Outputs: 1/3/2003 - %V,%G,%Y = 1,2003,2003
echo "1/3/2003 - %V,%G,%Y = " . strftime("%V,%G,%Y",strtotime("1/3/2003")) . "\n";

// Outputs: 1/10/2003 - %V,%G,%Y = 2,2003,2003
echo "1/10/2003 - %V,%G,%Y = " . strftime("%V,%G,%Y",strtotime("1/10/2003")) . "\n";
```

Comment: this is an example of the kind of date i get from $runrows['date']